# Error al usar matches (String) en java

Tags: java, regex, string, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

El problema es el siquiente, estoy intentando que un if me deje pasar solo cuando la cadena contenga numeros, letras o _, si contiene cualquier otro carácter no debería entrar al if.

EL codigo es algo así:

```
String letrasN = "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_]+";
String palabra ="i+[+";

if(palabra.matches(letrasN)){

   System.out.println("Estoy dentro");

}
```

El problema es que deja pasar Strings como la variable palabra, que contienen + , [ o ], cuando no debería.

¿Cuál puede ser el problema o que otra forma de hacer esto existe?

Answer (score 2):

*Esa expresión regular no está bien. Prueba con:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
```

No es que la expresión no funcione, es que no es la forma óptima de expresarla, aunque sólo sea por economía del lenguaje.

Tu código debería funcionar. Si no lo hace es igual porque algo falla en la parte de código que no has escrito. Te dejo una opción un poco más elaborada:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce palabra:");
        String palabra = sc.nextLine();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
        Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(palabra);

        if(mat.matches()){
            System.out.println("palabra válida");
        } else {
            System.out.println("palabra inválida");
        }        
    }
```

¿Podrías poner el código completo?

Comment: por que no esta bien? siempre considera explicar tu respuesta para que todos la entendamos

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con un pequeño código algo más elaborado. El que pasa debería funcionar pero puede resultar algo confuso. @element

Comment: muy bien, en este punto ya es mas clara +1